# Does the iPad Mini have a connectivity kit? (Need to transfer photos)

Tags: iphone, ipad

From what I've read, in order to connect my iPad mini to my iPhone 5, I need (1) a lightning to 30 pin adapter, and (2) an iPad Cammera Connection Kit, which has a 30pin to USB adapter. This is a bit cumbersome, so is there just a connection kit for the iPad Mini?

Note: I know that there are solutions such as iCloud and Dropbox, but those are limited in capacity, so I am looking to transfer photos to my iPad as another form of redundancy

Comment: Why do you want to connect an iPad to an iPhone ? Transfer photos ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes to transfer photos

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ipad mini has connectivity kit, since I have mine when I bought it but the truth is, I haven't been able to use it yet since I bought this last year!

And one more thing about transferring photos, I think it's better to use Dropbox, I guess your photos would not be too much to occupy even the 100GB capacity, which I am now using. I have iphone4s and ipad mini and I just sync everything to Dropbox, it's much easier, no hassle and simply a lot of storage capacity than my phone. :-)

Comment: Can you provide a link for the connectivity kit? The connectivity kit that I'm able to find is the 30-pin version (for older iPads), and that requires an adapter, which pretty much doubles the cost. I'm in need of one specifically for the iPad mini.